# Decrypt several password-pdf-protected files

Tags: find

I tried this command but I think something is wrong with `'{}' '{}'`. By the latter, I want `InputXYZ.pdf OutputXYZ.pdf` (I do not want any dupe files, I want to replace the old files to make reading a bit more convenient).

```
$ find . -name "*.pdf" -ok qpdf --password=passMe --decrypt '{}' '{}' \;
```

If you have better and simpler ideas to handle this kind of repetitive pass-typing probs with other programs, do not hesitate to comment or answer. Actually, my teachers use many different passwords and it is quite mess to read the documents. Perhaps, some file with their passwords and then just the `find` -cmd testing every possibility?

Answer (score 6):

You can't make the input file the same as the output file.  At best, `qpdf` will complain and not do anything.  At worst it will truncate the output file to zero bytes and then complain that the input file is empty.  So use this:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -ok qpdf --password=passMe --decrypt '{}' '{}'.decoded.pdf \;
```

You can go back and remove the dups once you know `qpdf` didn't trash your files in some unexpected way.

To avoid having the type 'y' and RETURN for each file, use the 'yes' command.  I.e.

```
yes | find . -name "*.pdf" -ok qpdf --password=passMe --decrypt '{}' '{}'.decoded.pdf \;
```

Comment: This is perfect except it requires that I type `y` after every iteration

Comment: @SpeedOfRound  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Given @[Kyle Jones' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29614/11539) as `decrypt_all_files_with()`, you could wrap everything in a for-loop,

```
for pass in $(cat passwords.txt)
  do decrypt_all_files_with($pass)
done
```

(but you possibly want to use `-exec` instead of `-ok`, as it doesn't ask for confirmation).